# How to create the pair without assembly in UniswapV2Factory

Tags: assembly, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

I'm going to deploy the Uniswap contract on my customized Ethereum.

Could I replace  [fancy footwork in the factory](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L32) by Solidity code?

I need to update this code `assembly { pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)}` into general solidity code.

I tried [this](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/guides/smart-contract-integration/getting-pair-addresses#examples), but not working well.

Comment: Stack Overflow questions can link external code for context, but the code you're directly asking about changing or fixing should always be in the question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
assembly {
  pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
}
```

I updated above code into

```
UniswapV2Pair newPair = new UniswapV2Pair();
IUniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1);
```

Comment: I don't think you can calculate the pair address offchain without using `create2`. However, it seems like with Solidity version 0.8, you can do it without using assembly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71121396/how-is-uniswap-assembly-create2-function-working

Answer (score 0):

Uniswap version 1 uses library contracts with hardcoded pair contract addresses.

- First deploy the factory contract
- Then call [Factory.pairCodeHash](https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap/blob/45da97206358039039883c4a99c005bb8a4bef0c/contracts/uniswapv2/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L26) - the hardcoded hex string of the init code
- Replace the pair code hash in the source code, compile the rest of the contracts

[More tips in this Python module](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/eth-hentai/blob/master/eth_hentai/uniswap_v2.py#L89).