# Getting the address of a contract by another one after inheritance

Tags: inheritance, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am new to Solidity and I've come up with this issue.
I want to develop a contract called `senderContract {}` that can receive ether from any address and then automatically transfer these funds to another contract called `receiverContract {}`. In this second contract, you will find two functions, the first one (`manualTransfer()`) is working correctly and allows to introduce manually the contract contract address to send the ether. But the second one (`autoTransfer()`) is not working.

I've discovered that the `constructor()` in the first contract changes the value of the variable `recipient` once the second contract es deployed. How is it possible that a variable in a constructor changes from its initialized value? Is the contructor not supposed to be executed just once?

Is there any reason for this action not being possible or am I just not writing the correct code? I leave the code here:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0 < 0.9.0;


 contract receiverContract {

    event Log(uint);
    address public recipient;

    constructor () {
        recipient = address(this);
    } 

    fallback () external payable {
        emit Log(gasleft());
    } 

    receive () external payable {}

    function getThisAddress() public view returns(address) {
        return address(this);
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}



contract senderContract is receiverContract {

    function manualTransfer (address payable _to) public payable {
        _to.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function autoTransfer () public payable {
        payable(recipient).transfer(msg.value);
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well, using the `super` functionality (look at the first line of the second contract); on remix, `recipent` and `_recipient` are the same. Basically, using "super." in inherited contracts applies what's after one level up, see https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html?highlight=super  :

```
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0 < 0.9.0;
```

```
contract receiverContract {

    event Log(uint);
    address public recipient;

    constructor () {
        recipient = address(this);
    } 

    fallback () external payable {
        emit Log(gasleft());
    } 

    receive () external payable {}

    function getThisAddress() public view returns(address) {
        return address(this);
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}



contract senderContract is receiverContract {

    address _recipient=super.getThisAddress();

// please see https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html?highlight=super 
//to understand how "super" works

    function manualTransfer (address payable _to) public payable {
        _to.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function autoTransfer () public payable {
        payable(_recipient).transfer(msg.value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor () {
    recipient = address(this);
}
```

Constructor is in fact executed just once - during the contract deployment. However, the value of `address(this)` *(the address of this contract)* is different each time you deploy the contract. Which results in the value of `recipient` also being different each time.

The address of newly deployed contract is, by default, determined from the deployer address and `nonce` of the deploying transaction. First transaction has nonce 0, second transaction has nonce 1, etc. So when you send a first transaction deploying a contract from the deployer address, it results in the contract address `0x123`. But a second transaction deploying a contract (any contract, even the same one) from the deployer address results in the contract address `0x456`.

---

If you want the deployed contract address to be always the same *(mind that you need to destruct the previously deployed contract before redeploying it)*, you can use the `create2` opcode (the non-default option). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123813/1693192) for more info.

Comment: Thank you Petr for your answer. I think I've understood the conceptual part of this issue, but I'm not sure about how to implement it. Would it be possible for you to share a small example of how to get this address using the nonce?

Comment: @RodrigoR The nonce is retrieved **in the background**, you don't explicitly use it in the code.. So if you want to deploy a contract from another contract (the factory pattern), you can just use the `new` keyword in Solidity: `new MyContract(constructorParams);` and it deploys new instance of `MyContract` to a new address (and the address is determined by the nonce in the background).